# Trying to understand the conversion from CSV to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

```
import csv
import json
import sys

csv_file = open('a1.csv','rU')

fields = ["bacteria", "Penicillin", "Streptomycin", "Neomycin", "Gram_Staining"]
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fields)
json_file = open('json_out.json', 'w')

json_reader = json.dumps([r for r in csv_reader], indent=0)
jsontodict = json.loads(json_reader)
json_file.write(json_reader)
```

I am converting a short CSV file into JSON so that I can add visualization with D3 later.
The code serves its purpose, but I want to understand how this works. (it was acquired from a website)

Q1: Does DictReader return DICT object? When I tried to print the return object, it was a "reader" object; hence it was unprintable, and I couldn't operate on it (search, etc).

Q2: How can I replace json.dumps(...) line with the following approach?
     for r in csv_reader:
    json_reader=json.dumps([r], indent=0)

Comment: Your question is a valid one, but is way too broad. In order to understand all of the underlying operations, you have to understand the basics of Python. In that case, you will need to understand inheritance (`DictReader` extends `reader`), iterators (`reader` is an iterator class), and streams (both the `json` and `csv` modules use them). I wouldn't go as far as downvoting you, but it's really too broad to answer. [Start at the top of the chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), and follow the links the documentation gives you.

Comment: Tip: if you ask a question about a *specific part* of the chain you do not understand, then it makes it suitable for Stack Overflow and you're likely to get quality answers for it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was reading the documentation and didn't quite follow it.

Comment: Would you mind showing how I can write "json_reader = json.dumps([r for r in csv_reader]" in for loop? I tried " for r in csv_reader: json_reader=json.dumps([r])", but it overwrites on the first row. Thank you,

Comment: You could go `stuff = [r for r in csv_reader]; json_reader = json.dumps(stuff)` to first collect all the data, then dump it. Dumping one item at a time inside the loop is wrong, or at least different, because it creates a stream of JSON objects, not one JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: DictReader returns a reader object -- an iterator that returns a dict on each iteration.  You can't print it directly, but list(rdr) will turn it into a list if you want.

Q2: json.dumps(list(rdr), indent=0)  ... [rdr] means a list containing a DictReader.